# Attribute value is null while trying to parse XML using dom4j

Tags: java, xml, parsing, xml-parsing

I am trying to parse a XML string using dom4j. But when I try to get the attribute value of any node(element) it return null value only.

This is my file contains XML:

```
<Event xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event'>
<System>
    <Provider Name='Outlook'/>
    <EventID Qualifiers='16384'>63</EventID>
    <Level>4</Level>
    <Task>0</Task>
    <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime='2015-07-23T13:45:26.000000000Z'/>
    <EventRecordID>27487</EventRecordID>
    <Channel>Application</Channel>
    <Computer>eGLAP0011-PC</Computer>
</System>
<EventData>
    <Data>The Exchange web service request GetAppManifests succeeded. </Data>
</EventData>
</Event>
```

See below my code:

```
BufferedReader br = null;
        try
        {
            File inputFile = new File("D:\\EventLog\\xml_op.txt");
            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(inputFile));
            String line="",con_line="";
            int inc =0;
            while((line = br.readLine())!=null)
            {
                con_line+=line;
            }
            Document doc=DocumentHelper.parseText(con_line);
            Element parent_ele = doc.getRootElement();

            for (Iterator i1 = parent_ele.elementIterator("System"); i1.hasNext();)
            {
                 Element Sys = (Element) i1.next();                
                 System.out.println("------------------------------------------------");
                 System.out.println("Provider--> " + Sys.attributeValue("Name")); //I got null value here
                 System.out.println("EventID--> " + Sys.elementText("EventID"));
                 System.out.println("Level--> " + Sys.elementText("Level"));
                 System.out.println("Task--> " + Sys.elementText("Task"));
                 System.out.println("Keywords--> " + Sys.elementText("Keywords"));
                 System.out.println("TimeCreated--> " + Sys.attributeValue("SystemTime"));//I got null value here
                 System.out.println("EventRecordID--> " + Sys.elementText("EventRecordID"));
                 System.out.println("Channel--> " + Sys.elementText("Channel"));
                 System.out.println("Computer--> " + Sys.elementText("Computer"));
                 System.out.println("------------------------------------------------");
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

The output of the above code:

```
------------------------------------------------
Provider--> null
EventID--> 63
Level--> 4
Task--> 0
Keywords--> 0x80000000000000
TimeCreated--> null
EventRecordID--> 27487
Channel--> Application
Computer--> eGLAP0011-PC
------------------------------------------------
```

In the above output, the value of Provider and Time Created is null,
I have searched lot in websites, but I didn't get correct solution for this problem, Please share your ideas. Thanks in advance,

Comment: You doesn't get directly `TimeCreated` Value form the file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current node is `<System>`. The `elementText()` function searches that node, get its text and prints it, but `attributeValue()` refers to current node, so you have to advance to the target and call it there, like:

```
System.out.println("Provider--> " + Sys.element("Provider").attributeValue("Name"));
```

and

```
System.out.println("TimeCreated--> " + Sys.element("TimeCreated").attributeValue("SystemTime"));
```

So, replace it in your code and give it a try. It yields:

```
------------------------------------------------
Provider--> Outlook
EventID--> 63
Level--> 4
Task--> 0
Keywords--> 0x80000000000000
TimeCreated--> 2015-07-23T13:45:26.000000000Z
EventRecordID--> 27487
Channel--> Application
Computer--> eGLAP0011-PC
------------------------------------------------
```